# Do Halo 1 through 3 have more comprehensive subtitles than Halo Reach in the Halo MCC on PC?

Tags: halo-the-master-chief-collection

I can't properly get into Halo: Reach on the PC Master Chief Collection because there are only subtitles in certain cutscenes, and none during gameplay. Do Halo 1, 2 and 3 also have this problem, or do these games have proper subtitles outside of the cutscenes?

Comment: Only a comment because I'm not sure, but I also had subtitles also only in cutscenes in Halo 1 and 2